# Is it possible to make a Test Method generic while using MSTest as test framework?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I am  trying to unit test a generic method which takes a generic delegate as one of the argument. This method has more than 15 references and those references pass different function pointer as parameter. Here, my effort is to pass the different function pointer along with other parameters and test the functionality contained in that actual method.

```
  [TestMethod]    
  [DynamicData("TestMethodParameterSets", DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]    
  public void SomeMethodToTest_WhenSomeOperationFails_ShouldLogSomeExceptionMessage<T, R>(               
   T model, SomeActionDelg<T, R> callbackAction)        
   {
          repository.Setup(..some setup here ..);    

          var result = _controller.SomeMethodToTest(model, callbackAction) as RedirectToRouteResult;

          _log.Verify(x => x.Error(It.IsAny<object>()));
   }    

   public IEnumerable<object[]> TestMethodParameterSets()     
    {    
          var model = new SomeModelClass();

          return new[]
          {
              new object[] { model, (Func<SomeModelClass, int>) SomeOtherMethodToExecute},
              //new object[] { model2, (Func<SomeModelClass2, int>) SomeOtherMethodToExecute2}
              //more values
          };
   }
```

And, this is how the delegate and main method to be tested look like;

```
  public delegate R SomeActionDelg<T, R>(T model); 

  public ActionResult SomeMethodToTest<T, R>(T model, SomeActionDelg<T, R> callbackAction) 

   {     

  //  some more code here     

   }
```

The problem with this code is, MSTest doesn't detect the test method because of being generic.  So, if anyone has done similar thing or have any idea whether MSTest allows us to write generic test method or not, please feel free to answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: MSTest does not support this. You will need to create a standard test method that then tests (or calls through) to the generic methods.

Comment: The method which will call `SomeMethodToTest_WhenSomeOperationFails_ShouldLogSomeExceptionMessage` should be a test method.

Comment: Even if MSTest could detect the method, the method is really just a template until type parameters are provided. Which version of it would you want it to run? Do you expect it to iterate over all of `T` and `R`?

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your prompt response. Initially, even I was thinking about using that approach mentioned by @Igor and Chetan but couldn't go further because if the test fails for specific set of arguments, it will be harder for other developers or testers to locate the error.

Comment: @Igor unfortunately, then the `TestInitialize` method is not called automatically for every call to the generic method and must be called manually where required